# Jaxb unmarshalling not throwing any exception when data type mismatch

Tags: java, jaxb

I am attempting to unmarshal string value to integer, It returns default value of int instead of throwing exceptions. is there any solution to handle exception. 
because i need original value[aa] for logging purposes.

```
public class TestJAXB {

    public static void main (String a[]) {
        String xml = "<Message><age>aa</age><name>shas</name></Message>";   
        try {
            JAXBContext j = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestBean.class);
            Unmarshaller u = j.createUnmarshaller();
            TestBean o = (TestBean) u.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
            System.out.println("Age "+o.getAge()); // returns 0 instead of throwing exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class TestBean {
    @XmlElement
    private int age = 0;
    @XmlElement
    private String name = null;
}
```

Comment: It might be a duplicate of this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095314/would-like-unknown-attributes-to-error-when-jaxb-unmarshalling